# Complexity for minimum subset sum of size n-k

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

Disclaimer: Not a HW.

Given $n$ sorted positive floating point numbers, and one has to find the minimum subset sum of size $n-k$. What would be the most efficient way? I can figure out using Brute force becomes $O(n^{n-k})$

Answer (score 0):

Since all floating points are positive,  we can conclude that we should greedily pick the smallest $n-k$ floating point numbers for the smallest sum. This can be proven by the exchange argument that any solution that does not follow the greedy strategy can be improved by making swaps accodring to the greedy strategy.

Since the list is already sorted, the complexity will be $\mathcal{O}(n-k)$